# Solve $\int_{-1}^1 f(x,t) \, dx=\log \left(\frac{t+1}{1-t}\right)$

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to find a function $f(x,t)$ so that
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x,t) \, dx=\log \left(\frac{t+1}{1-t}\right)\text{?}$$
I tried the Laplace transform, but it did not work.

Comment: If it's easy (as you say it is in the title), why do you need help?

Comment: i just change it sorry

Comment: A pretty obvious guess works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f(x,t)= \frac{t}{tx+1}$. Then $\int_{-1}^1 f(x,t)=[ln(x+\frac{1}{t})]_{x=-1}^{x=1}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that 
$$f(x,t) = \frac{t}{1+x\cdot t}$$
is a solution because of the RHS being
$$\log(1+t) - \log(1-t) \ ,$$
so the desired antiderivative is
$$F(x,t) = \log(1+x \cdot t)$$
I guess you could derive that conclusively (without the need of any intuition) with a single differentiation w.r.t. $x$.

Answer (score -1):

Easy!$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{t+1}{1-t}\right)dx = \log\left(\frac{t+1}{1-t}\right)
$$